# Purpose of Adding Capability to Role But Not Grant?

Tags: user-roles, capabilities

I am attempting to create a custom role upon activation of my plugin. Along with that role,  I wanted to add new capability to that role to access later.  Now, after reading the [Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_cap), I am totally confused.  What is the purpose of the grant parameter?  What good would it do to add a capability to a user/role and not grant access to it when WordPress doesn't offer access to check if the capability is granted? The `has_cap` method only returns true or false.

At this point, it looks like the direction I should go is just create new Roles and either assign those roles to my users or not.  The capabilities were going to be a "neat" way of me adding the custom capabilities without cluttering up the role list when manually adding a user. It looks like this won't work for me.  Anyone confirm what I am reading/finding?